# Is this an error in the book or am I missing something? Proof that an imaginary number z is equal to it's conjugate (no mention of b = 0).

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Ok, so here's what I have in the textbook:

> Prove: For any complex number $z\in C$, $\overline{z} = z$.
>
> Suppose that $z = a + bi$ where $a,b \in R$.

The proof:

> $\overline{z} = a+bi = \overline{\overline{a-bi}} = a-(-b)i = a+bi = z$

Isn't the solution already assuming that the conjugate of z is equal to z by stating that $\overline{z}= a +bi$ when they defined $z = a+bi$ ?

I know this is true when $b = 0$, but there's no reference to $b=0$ in the book, I wrote all there is.

Edit: The book is Schaum's outlines Linear Algebra, 5th edition.

Edit 2: I checked in the 6th edition, to see if it was a typo that had been fixed. It is exactly the same in the 6th edition as in the 5th edition.

Edit 3: I put the parts of the book in quotes. They are not direct quotes as there are 2 other problems in the book, but the 2 others are not relevant to this one. If you want the original thing here is a picture of the whole thing (I highlighted the parts that I wrote in the question): [image]

Comment: I think the proof is for the conjugate of the conjugate of $z$ is $z$.

Comment: If you have transcribed it correctly, then there are typos in the book.

Comment: I have transcribed correctly. But there would be more than 1 typo no? Because the proof doesn't seem to make sense even if we replace the $\overline{z}$ with $\overline{\overline{z}}$. Unless I'm missing something there too.

Comment: It's not clear from your post what portions come exactly from the book, what portion is transcribed from the book, what portion is interpolated from the book, and what portion is you talking. Perhaps you can highlight things to make this clear, otherwise it's a bit hard to guess where the issue might lie.

Comment: I edited the details and added a screenshot of the original part of the book. (I didn't add a picture before because I couldn't add pictures in the question since it is my first question on this website.)

Comment: IMO, nobody would write $\bar z=z$ and attempt to prove it (even wrongly). So $\bar{\bar z}=z$ is more likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo, the item (iii) is really wrong. It may be $\overline{\overline{z}}=z$. So, the proof is good:

$$\overline{\overline{z}}=\overline{a-bi}=a-(-b)i=a+bi=z$$

Good studies!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Here in MathExchange you could accept the answers that help you (only a detail).

Comment: Thank you! I opened an account just for this question, but I might used it more when needed. This was very helpful and fast!